# Java add text to textArea and textField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, jtextarea

I am trying to make a JTextArea and a JTextField that has pre-set text in it already so when the user clicks in the box, they can edit it so something else.

Here's what I have for my text field:

```
private JTextField gridSizeField = new JTextField(6);
```

and my text area:

```
private JTextArea status = new JTextArea(20, 20);
private JScrollPane statusScroller = new JScrollPane(status);
```

Comment: Did you even glance at the documentation before asking?

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the overloaded constructors that accepts a String as an argument.

```
JTextField(String text, int columns)

JTextField gridSizeField = new JTextField("Your Text", 15);
```

Same for JTextArea

```
JTextArea(String text, int rows, int cols)

JTextArea status = new JTextArea("Your status", 20, 20);
```

You should have referred to the JavaDocs first

More on [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) and [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to have text already set inside the JTextArea, it is a parameter of the JTextArea constructor. For example, to have the string "Text already in JTextArea", you just have to do

```
  private JTextArea status = new JTextArea("Text already in JTextArea", 20, 20);
  private JTextField field = new JTextField("Text already in JTextField", 6);
```

Hope it helps!